# InnoDB full-text-search deadlock

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, innodb

I have a medium-volume application that does about 40 inserts per second. All inserts are in the format of:

```
UPDATE item SET values=... WHERE row_id='18273-3749d-8743'
```

Furthermore, no item is updated multiple times at the same time. It seems simple enough and there should never be a deadlock if we ignore everything else. However, I have a `fulltext` field that seems to acquire a pseudo-table level lock, instead of a row-level lock, if I'm troubleshooting this correctly. Here is the error that it gives on `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`:

```
LATEST DEADLOCK DETECTED
...
RECORD LOCKS space ... index FTS_DOC_ID_INDEX of table
```

So, if I'm interpreting this correctly, it seems like **FTS_DOC_ID_INDEX** is doing some sort of "more-than-row-level-lock" to update the search index. Is this what is occurring? And if so, what's the correct way to deal with this -- as in, I cannot decrease the number of writes to the application, is there a way to do a "safe update" (?) on the FTS field? Or do I need to  write the `update`s such that I remove the `fts` field and queue those separately (which would seem like a huge pain to do). What's the best way to deal with this?

Comment: Please show us the entire text of the "deadlock" section of the STATUS, and the conflicting SELECT.

Comment: If you would SET GLOBAL innodb_print_all_deadlocks=1; the system will record each deadlock encountered in your error log. To stop the logging of deadlocks, SET GLOBAL innodb_print_all_deadlocks=0; after 2 hours. Post the last 2 hours of your error log for us to have a look at the cause, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(After seeing the `SELECT`, etc`, I may have a better answer, but here is starting advice.)

Whenever you *may* get a deadlock, you should provide in your code for recovering from it.  That is, check for deadlock after doing the `UPDATE`, then re-execute the update once.

Comment: could you please show an example in code/SQL on how to do this, and I can award the bounty?

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 - What is your application language?  (The code will vary.)  Is the `UPDATE` a part of a longer transaction, or is it run with autocommit=ON.

Comment: more or less autocommit on. I do: `cursor.execute('...'); conn.commit('...')` in python. So one statement then I run commit.

Comment: Hmmm... Nothing obvious.  So my only advice is to add code recover from the deadlock.  You could also devise a small, reproducible, test case and file a bug report at bugs.mysql.com .